# How do I create monte carlo results on a graph using parameter variation experiment on anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on the evacuation time of pedestrians by running 100 runs using monte carlo. I have trouble creating the graphs and am very confused in the steps. Something is missing and I am not sure what it is.

I have created a parameter variation experiment page and included a Histogram2D data and a graph from analysis but I don't know how to read the data I want from the main.

Below image is the data I am trying to acquire from the timeMeasureEnd which isn't linked yet. 
[image]

I use the code
`root.timeEnd`
 but get this error as shown below
[image]

Comment: Your command is somehow interpreted as a variable declaration. I am not sure why, but it seems that you need to anything with your root.timeEnd to avoid this interpretation. For example try traceln(root.timeEnd), this should work.

Comment: It is says The method traceIn(DataSet) is undefined for the type ParametersVariation. 
In my first image I think I did not set my data properly. How can I link timeEnd with timeMeasureEnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access the timeMeasureEnd's internal dataset: timeMeasureEnd.dataset. See the AnyLogic example model *Measuring Length of Stay*, referenced in the [documentation](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FTimeMeasureEnd.html).

As for your error, your statement gets interpreted as a variable declaration. As soon as you put some useful code in there it works, eg. a simple assignment to a local dataset in your Experiment class:

```java
dataset = root.timeMeasureEnd.dataset;
```

[image: Experiment Dataset]

To save the longest measured time after each run:

- add a  dataset, deactivate *update automatically*
- add a integer variable `iteration` to save the current iteration index
- use the following in *After Simulation run* code:

```java
iteration++;
dataset.add(iteration,root.timeMeasureEnd.dataset.getYMax());
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you so much sir. It does work and I can see the results change after every run when I click on the dataset. But is there a possibility where I can save those data or show it in graph or table? For example for 100 runs I would like to obtain or store all the results for total evacuation time during each run?

Comment: There are many options, depends on how you want to aggregate and show the data... You can write to file, write to database, aggregate to average value and collect those in another dataset...You have endless possibilities, thats another question on its own and depends highly on your requirements. For the total evacuation time, where do you collect this in your model? Or do you mean the max of the timeMeasurements? Anyway, just access it after model run and save it in a dataset in Experiment and visualize it.

Comment: Oh I understand. I only want the max evacuation time for each run. I'll create another question then on this issue but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If I create a graph using the dataset set, why don't I see any results shown on the graph? I can see my results when i click on dataset but no changes on the graph.

Comment: You need to define whats on the x axis maybe? Normally thats timestamps, but since you store the values in experiment, you have no time. Thus you'll have to define a value for x axis, maybe run number from 1 to 100?

Comment: I updated the answer, this should work now as you described it

Comment: Yes it works perfectly now. Thank you so much, I still have more to do with my work I hope you will have the time to help me sir. I'll keep posting questions.